# How to insert a named-range of spreadsheet cells into Google Slides

Tags: google-sheets, google-slides

Google Slides has the ability to insert a chart object (Google-sheets). This instance in the slide can be dynamically updated each time the source-chart is changed.  Chart insertion is performed by navigating: Google-Slides => Insert => Chart => From Sheets.

Likewise, the goal is to embed a **named-range of Google Sheets cells** and embed it into a Google Slides presentation.   Is it possible to somehow alias the named-range as a chart so that it can be pulled in via the same mechanism and updated when?

Answer (score 3):

Name a range
Open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
Select the cells you want to name.
Click Data > Named ranges. A menu will open on the right.
Type the range name you want.
To change the range, click Spreadsheet.
Select a range in the spreadsheet or type the new range into the text box, then
click Ok.
Click Done.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to insert a named range into a Google sheet:

```
={name_of_range}
```

Comment: That's great! I don't suppose you could quote the announcement or link to the support page to back this up?

Comment: An example or reference to an example is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At this time it's not possible to embed a named-range in Google Slides but you could use the Table Chart that use a reference of the form Sheet1!A1:B5 and then insert the resulting chart to a Google Slides presentation. For details see [Chart types - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190718?hl=en)